# Preventing the Osama Facebook worm

Tags: javascript, security

There is a [javascript worm](http://pastebin.com/uk0NZ758) spreading on facebook.  The worm tricks users into executing javascript by [copying and pasting the payload into the address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jvZf.png). This is **not xss**,  this is social engineering.   If you read the worm's source code you'll see that its riding on the session and forging requests like the Sammy worm.  What are some way that a web application can prevent this type of attack?

Comment: @Gumbo♦ yeah a browser can do that,  but running noscript is even better. I'm asking what can a web application do?

Comment: @Gumbo: That's a start, but doesn't stop the worm from instructing the user to 'first type "javascript", followed by a colon and then paste the code below' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Education is the best and only way.

Comment: Educating who? The users? Seems a bit naive.

Comment: @peirix: Impractical, perhaps. Naive.. why?

Comment: I'd say it's naive to think that users of a site like facebook have either the time or will to learn about stuff like this. Sure, they'd benefit from it, and they _should_ want to learn, but I just think it's too far-fetched to say this is a viable solution.

Comment: @peirix: I don't particularly disagree. We need to change that and educate users. That's what I mean.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I absolutely like your answer...maybe I should change it from naive to _idealistic_, at least that don't have as many negative associations to it.

Comment: @peirix: Hehe, you could do that. I do understand your view, though; don't worry about it. :)

Answer (score 4):

If we're talking about a malicious user script manipulating the DOM (like this one seems to be doing):

You could ensure all the native JS code is hidden away from the global scope (through closures) and then hijack the `document` property of `window`. There can be ways a worm can circumvent this, but it will surely make things harder.

This is not something I've actually attempted and have proven to work, but the basic idea is:

```
(function () {
    // Initialize page

    // When we're done, make document inaccessible
    window.document = null;
})();
```

The pretense is, all native code that's executed during page initialization (including jQuery code etc.) should be bound to the actual `document` object through closure. It should not be possible for "javascript:" code in the address bar to access the actual document by executing in the global scope.

Again, I might be missing something blatantly flawed with this idea, and I'm ready to embrace all the downvotes. Maybe there are additional steps that need to be taken to completely hide away `document`.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Rook: I've added to my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this break events that handles the DOM in any way? For instance, click-event code won't be evaluated until they are fired, right? And by then the document is "gone"..?

Comment: @peirix: The event handler function should be bound to the actual document object by then.

Comment: This won't work, at least not in Chrome. You cannot overwrite certain properties: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/WVasw/

Comment: @Felix Kling: At first, I was suspicious that jsfiddle might be doing some sort of sandboxing to give that result, but you're right, testing with a plain old HTML locally, I saw that I can neither reassign `window.document` nor `window` itself :(

Answer (score 2):

For social engineering worms such as this exceedingly simple one, it should all come down to education. It is an awareness issue, as are most social engineering problems.

I see so many individuals who seem to fall for every facebook scam, and this one should be way more simple to avoid than most as it actually requires a user to type in commands. But people are desperate to see pictures of a dead terrorist. WTF?

The tricky thing is how to persuade them that while what they are doing may not hurt them directly, it does cost. It is the same problem as trying to persuade home users to run antivirus and firewalls - many don't even care if they are infected and are running as part of a botnet, as long as they can play their games and surf the net.

Technically - it could be done by facebook, but it won't be. You could prevent this propagating by simply pattern matching and removal of key signatures. It would just take too much effort, and as soon as you had sorted a specific issue there would be a way round it.

**tl;dr** - Educate EVERYONE! Long job, and unwinnable, but worth keeping on trying.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple fix is to force your users to use a browser window without an address bar.  Although this solution comes with its own problems.

Another solution is using javascript and/or [flash](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) its possible to interact with the clipboard. A check could execute whenever a ctrl+c event (or a timer) is fired. If the message starts with `javascript:` then a blank message or a warning is copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about ways to protect your website's users against this form of attack (ie. cookie stealing) I'm assuming that the following basic steps would help, of course there's a lot more you could do and this small list isn't at all comprehensive:

1. Don't let users post Javascript! :-)
2. Encrypt your cookies' data with a private key so that only your web app can utilise the data within
3. Lock down sessions to IP, so if somebody stole the cookie / session cookie, it could not be reused

Comment: **None of this will stop the worm.**  Its more like a CSRF attack in that it reads the csrf token and forges request within the session.   The Sammy worm did this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's really no way to stop the user from executing javascript in the context of your web app.  You could post a note warning users not to paste scripts that they don't understand in the address bar, or you could try to obfuscate your client code, but none of this will do much to stop the problem.  In the case of obfuscated code, it just takes a little more work for the scammer to write usable code.

Since the code executes in the context of your webapp, you have no foolproof way to tell apart legitimate user actions from script-based actions once the request gets to the server.  The best you can do is try to use a heuristic to detect fishy requests and stop them.